# Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0__does not exist on this mock object

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

When running phpunit I get the following error:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Method Mockery_0__Tests_Unit_App_Utils_Blueprints_BlueprintRuleUtil::executeActiveBlueprintRules() does not exist on this mock object

The test method that is failing is:

```
public function testExecuteActiveBlueprintRulesShouldExecuteDefaultOutsourceCostRule()
{
    Strategy::fake();

    Strategy::create(['id' => 1]);
    $createdStrategy = Strategy::getCreatedModel();

    /**
     * We can use a partial mock for BlueprintRuleUtil so we can mock specific methods
     * later on using shouldReceive while still being able to call regular methods on the class
     * including the one we are testing in this test case.
     */
    $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock = \Mockery::mock(App\Utils\Blueprints\BlueprintRuleUtil::class)->makePartial();

    /**
     * For method chaining with the DB facade
     * we want to use mockery to mock each chained method
     * and use andReturnSelf() to return an instance of the
     * returned value until we reach the last method call in the chain.
     *
     * Then we can return the final result that we should be expecting
     * which is likely a stdClass object as a query result.
     */
    $active_blueprint_rule = new stdClass();
    $active_blueprint_rule->id = 1001;

    DB::shouldReceive("table")
        ->with('blueprint_rules')
        ->once()->andReturnSelf();

    DB::shouldReceive("where")
        ->with('is_active', true)
        ->andReturnSelf();

    DB::shouldReceive("get")
        ->andReturn([$active_blueprint_rule]);

    $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->shouldReceive('addDefaultOutsourceCostToStrategy')
        ->withAnyArgs();
    $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->shouldReceive('shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost')->withAnyArgs()->andReturn(true);

    $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->executeActiveBlueprintRules($createdStrategy);

    Strategy::stopFaking();
}
```

Here is the full test class I am using:

```php
namespace Tests\Unit;

/**
 * Need to use built in laravel testcase instead of PHPUnit testcase to have access to instance variables like app for mocking
 */

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Strategy;
use App\Pillar;
use App\Utils\Blueprints\BlueprintRuleUtil;
use DB;
use stdClass;

class BlueprintRuleUtilTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Test to make sure outsource cost will not be added
     * with a certain blueprint type and pillars.
     */
    public function testShouldAddDefaultSnowflakeOutsourceCostWillReturnFalse()
    {
        Strategy::fake();
        Pillar::fake();

        Strategy::create(['id' => 1]);

        // test core business first
        Pillar::create(['id' => 1, 'slug' => 'core-new-business']);

        $createdStrategy = Strategy::getCreatedModel();
        // set the pillar to be the created model so it can grab it's pillar property later on using a relation
        $createdStrategy->pillar = Pillar::getCreatedModel();

        $blueprint_rule_util = new BlueprintRuleUtil();

        $this->assertFalse($blueprint_rule_util->shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost($createdStrategy));

        // test service expansion by updating the pillar
        $createdStrategy->pillar->slug = 'service-expansion';
        $this->assertFalse($blueprint_rule_util->shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost($createdStrategy));

        // test with blueprint type set to project and valid pillar slug
        $createdStrategy->pillar->slug = 'resign';
        $createdStrategy->type = 'project';
        $this->assertFalse($blueprint_rule_util->shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost($createdStrategy));

        Strategy::stopFaking();
        Pillar::stopFaking();
    }

    /**
     * Test given a valid slug and project type that the
     * Snowflake default outsource cost is added
     */
    public function testShouldAddDefaultSnowflakeOutsourceCostWillReturnTrue()
    {
        Strategy::fake();
        Pillar::fake();

        Strategy::create(['id' => 1]);

        $blueprint_rule_util = new BlueprintRuleUtil();

        // test resign which is a valid pillar
        Pillar::create(['id' => 1, 'slug' => 'resign']);

        $createdStrategy = Strategy::getCreatedModel();
        // test with valid type retainer
        $createdStrategy->type = 'retainer';
        // set the pillar to be the created model so it can grab it's pillar property later on using a relation
        $createdStrategy->pillar = Pillar::getCreatedModel();
        $this->assertTrue($blueprint_rule_util->shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost($createdStrategy));

        Strategy::stopFaking();
        Pillar::stopFaking();
    }

    public function testExecuteActiveBlueprintRulesShouldExecuteDefaultOutsourceCostRule()
    {
        Strategy::fake();

        Strategy::create(['id' => 1]);
        $createdStrategy = Strategy::getCreatedModel();

        /**
         * We can use a partial mock for BlueprintRuleUtil so we can mock specific methods
         * later on using shouldReceive while still being able to call regular methods on the class
         * including the one we are testing in this test case.
         */
        $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock = \Mockery::mock(App\Utils\Blueprints\BlueprintRuleUtil::class)->makePartial();

        /**
         * For method chaining with the DB facade
         * we want to use mockery to mock each chained method
         * and use andReturnSelf() to return an instance of the
         * returned value until we reach the last method call in the chain.
         *
         * Then we can return the final result that we should be expecting
         * which is likely a stdClass object as a query result.
         */
        $active_blueprint_rule = new stdClass();
        $active_blueprint_rule->id = 1001;

        DB::shouldReceive("table")
            ->with('blueprint_rules')
            ->once()->andReturnSelf();

        DB::shouldReceive("where")
            ->with('is_active', true)
            ->andReturnSelf();

        DB::shouldReceive("get")
            ->andReturn([$active_blueprint_rule]);

        $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->shouldReceive('addDefaultOutsourceCostToStrategy')
            ->withAnyArgs();
        $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->shouldReceive('shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost')->withAnyArgs()->andReturn(true);

        $blueprint_rule_util_partial_mock->executeActiveBlueprintRules($createdStrategy);

        Strategy::stopFaking();
    }
}
```

Here is the class I am testing against:

```php
namespace App\Utils\Blueprints;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Strategy;
use App\StrategyCost;

class BlueprintRuleUtil
{
    const DEFAULT_OUTSOURCE_COST_RULE_ID = 1001;

    /**
     * Iterate through the active blueprint rules and execute them based on their name
     *
     * @param Strategy $strategy
     *
     */
    public function executeActiveBlueprintRules(Strategy $strategy)
    {
        if (!is_null($strategy)) {
            $active_blueprint_rules = DB::table('blueprint_rules')
                ->where('is_active', true)
                ->get();

            foreach ($active_blueprint_rules as $active_blueprint_rule) {
                if (!is_null($active_blueprint_rule) && $active_blueprint_rule->id === self::DEFAULT_OUTSOURCE_COST_RULE_ID) {
                    BlueprintRuleUtil::addDefaultOutsourceCostToStrategy($strategy, $active_blueprint_rule);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Given a strategy (blueprint)
     *
     * Return true if we should add the default outsource cost to it
     * false if not based on the blueprint type and pillar
     *
     * @param Strategy $strategy
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost(Strategy $strategy)
    {
        $pillar_slugs_to_exclude_for_outsource_costs = [
            'core-new-business',
            'service-expansion'
        ];
        if (
            in_array($strategy->pillar->slug, $pillar_slugs_to_exclude_for_outsource_costs)
            || $strategy->type === 'project'
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Create a StrategyCost entry in the db for the provided strategy
     * using the amount from the active blueprint rule to add the default outsource cost.
     *
     * @param Strategy $strategy
     * @param object $active_blueprint_rule
     */
    public function addDefaultOutsourceCostToStrategy(Strategy $strategy, object $active_blueprint_rule)
    {
        if (self::shouldAddDefaultOutsourceCost($strategy)) {
            $department_slug = 'data-intelligence';
            $department = DB::table('departments')
                ->where('slug', $department_slug)
                ->first();

            if (!is_null($department)) {
                $strategy_cost = new StrategyCost;
                $strategy_cost->name = 'Snowflake';
                $strategy_cost->department_id = $department->id;
                $strategy_cost->strategy_id = $strategy->id;
                // set first month to outsource cost
                $strategy_cost->month_1 = $active_blueprint_rule->amount;
                $strategy_cost->save();
                $strategy_cost->strategy->recalculate();
            } else {
                Log::debug("BlueprintRuleUtil: department $department_slug not found, did not add default outsource cost");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using the full class name path with the namespace as the argument when creating the partial mock. I thought that might fix it because it may not be loading the right object. However that didn't work.

The method name is in the class that I am mocking. I'm not sure why I continue to get this error.

Comment: Why are you trying to mock a `DB` class? Never ever mock database calls nor modelds, yuo need to explain more why are you doing this so we can help you. Check out my profile and see if any of the links in there is of help. Also, you should not be using `DB` but a real Model, that is the Laravel way, else you are missusing Laravel and will be just more complex for you (you can't use scopes, attributes setters and getters, casts, events, and relationships, that is the most important part)

Comment: @matiaslauriti the reason I am using DB is because without abstraction using models, sql queries run significantly faster. There are cases where using DB works better at scale.

The reason we are mocking the DB class is so we can run these tests in our pipeline in isolation without having to connect to an actual database. It's to test the underlying logic of the function independent of the database. That is one of the main attractions to using mocking libraries.

Comment: You are right about the idea of using mocks, but the DB have stuff behind scenes that you could be not mocking (not knowing they happen) so the test could pass, but in reality you are removing core code, for example, a model having a scope, if you have a scope and you mock a model, you could be removing them or all of them, that means you are now changing how stuff works (in your test) so the real world application is going to use the scope, but not your test. Related to using DB instead of models because of performance, it is neglectable, Laravel = Eloquent, so not using it is just crazy

Comment: If you have serious performance issues, I would recommend switching to Lumen, and if you still have issues, switch to another framework or language, like Rust or Go. Else, not using a Model is just madness, makes everything a lot easier. I understand if you cannot change it, in that case, I will not be able to help because, as I said before, mocking a model or eloquent could mean you are not correctly mocking everything, so the test does 1 thing but the real app passes over more code you wheer not aware of it existed, be very careful with it

Comment: I don't believe I should have to test built in model code that Laravel has already tested. Testing should be reserved for custom code (which you can have in models) but in this case there isn't anything custom.

My question is less about mocking the DB class and more about create a partial mock of my class. I'm not having any issues mocking the DB class, the real issue is that the partialMock is not registering a method to exist, which I need to call

Comment: Eloquent does not perform well with large queries at scale. Also sometimes it requires a lot of boilerplate code to do very simple operations. It's not always the answer. Here is an article I read about it https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-Laravel-model-slower-than-the-query-builder. Also we had a query go from taking 3 min to run to taking 1 min by switching from eloquent to DB operations. The abstraction can be a performance hitter

Comment: I would still use a fake database, as you have stuff behind scenes. Mocking the DB facade is complicated because you could be ignoring that hidden behavior, and if Laravel changes something in between versions (you need to upgrade), you may need to change the mock and that is a bigger pain in the known part... I would still stick to Models, unless you need a super specific refined query, but eloquent (models) work as expected... it will not work as expected when you need to work with 1k+ or 5k+ results (you sohuld never get that amount in memory), but it is your project, your suffering

Comment: I have no idea why it is failing to execute the method, throwing that error, you are not doing anything wrong. I would try to comment out the previous `shouldReceive`, just to see if you are then getting the method to work

Comment: ok cool i can try that thanks

Comment: @matiaslauriti it's a good idea, and we might do that, we just started this testing process and its what runs fast and that i have experience with. but we can try something else if it becomes too difficult. thanks for the advice!